# Best practice for log-in procedure in a conference-app

Tags: login, password, ios

I'm preparing an app for a closed conference with log-in functionality. All the participants are on an email-list.

How do other App's deal with the challenges around obtaining the initial username/password, then get the user to log-in and also dealing with forgotten passwords.

Know of some good examples?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a few examples of good sign up UX.

Here are a few:

- [Test Flight](https://testflightapp.com/register/)
- [Facebook](http://patterntap.com/tap/pattern/12599120784c899b7cad672)
- [CulinaryCulture](http://patterntap.com/tap/pattern/1533356244ac612ebc6336)
- [GrooveShark](http://patterntap.com/tap/pattern/1388845259487b48eee5f06)

Comment: ...these all look fine...but do you please also know of places where the issue has been that the list is closed and only for selected people?

Comment: Like a Beta? I dont quite get what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

An awesome example is how StackExchange does it.

The user can login using an existing account, if they have one,  from Google, Yahoo, OpenID, and Facebook. The user can choose to create a new account if he/she wishes.

Comment: Our login will only be available for few selected people. Do you please know of any invite based systems?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking to do something that's quite common, especially in Web applications.  It's not clear for which platform you're writing the app but you might look to Skype for best practices signing up, signing in, and otherwise servicing users intending to participate in a conference.  Skype has a desktop app, mobile apps, and a high-functionality Website.

Comment: ...do you please know of other examples than Skype where the invites/attendees are at a closed list?

Comment: You might check out video conferencing systems like Vidyo or GoToMeeting.  You can get a free 30-day trial for GoToMeeting; create some fake events and invite coworkers or your own alternate email addresses; see what the experience is like from both ends.

Also, if you want examples of login UIs, I just found this great collection:
http://ui-patterns.com/explore/collections/account-registration